# Service for User to Self

Tags: kerberos

When it comes to Windows permissions a security principal (Admin1) can gather information on another security principal (User1) e.g. their (SID) and group membership (Group SIDS). Then take this list of SIDS and compare it to an ACL (for example on a file/folder) to check if this other security principal (User1) has rights to a given resource

there is some basic information at the [this link](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh553721.aspx)

The thing I do not quite understand at the moment is 'under what identity' does Admin1 request User1 SID and User1 Group SIDs

for example in the above link the MSDN talks about Kerberos, and my understanding of Kerberos is the TGT or ST is encrypted using the hash of the security principals (SPN) password e.g. either the password has for krbtgt for TGTs and the password has for the SPN for a given SPN (like a CIFS service).

I understand the service/session (in 'Service for User to Self') requests a Kerberos service ticket ST for 'itself' and therefore the service is able to decrypt the ST to extract the SIDs

However what gives the Service/session the 'right' to ask for SIDs for another user?
is it simply because any security principal authentication to AD can 'read' attributes of another security principal and therefore request this list? I assume so

I am not a programmer, but rather a Micrsoft Server/System engineer

Comment: Long story short: on the AD DC, Kerberos (port 88) handles authentication, and LDAP (ports 389 etc) handles all the attributes of users, including the groups they belong to. You will notice when running `klist` that, on login, your session gets a TGT _and_ a service ticket for LDAP. Same for service accounts, they are "authentified" when running requests. I guess you can restrict access with ACLs... but by default about anyone/anything can run LDAP queries once authentified.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to reply to my question Samson. it is people like you that take a few minutes out of their day that help me learn :)

Comment: By coincidence I was tinkering with `ldapsearch` on Linux this afternoon (with Linux authentication/authorization bound to AD) and trying to get the groups a specific user belonged to. Works quite well when you take care of cross-domain issues (global catalog etc.) Actually AD accepts 3 kinds of authentication when called by non-MS clients: GSSAPI i.e. non-MS raw Kerberos, GSS-SPNego (Kerberos wrapper for REST and web UIs) and plain user/pwd -- with user either in LDAP style (full DN string) or Windows style (domn\id) or Kerberos style (id@DOMN)

Comment: Thanks very much again Samson,